# TSQL Large Data Set Merge

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have two data sets (190 Million Rows and 100 Million Rows). I need to find the most effective way to merge the two together with no duplicate rows. I can do this via TSQL commands or an SSIS process. Does anyone have any input/experience as to what the most effective way to complete this process is?

Both tables have the same formatting:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table01]( 
    [StudentId] [char](10) NOT NULL, 
    [CollegeId] [char](6) NOT NULL, 
    [TermId] [char](3) NOT NULL, 
    [CourseId] [char](12) NULL, 
    [Title] [char](68) NULL, 
    [SectionId] [char](6) NULL, 
    [UnitsEarned] [decimal](5, 2) NULL, 
    [Grade] [char](3) NULL, 
    [CreditFlag] [char](1) NULL, 
    [UnitsAttempted] [decimal](5, 2) NULL, 
    [TopCode] [char](6) NULL, 
    [TransferStatus] [char](1) NULL, 
    [UnitsMax] [decimal](5, 2) NULL, 
    [BSStatus] [char](1) NULL, 
    [SamCode] [char](1) NULL, 
    [ClassCode] [char](1) NULL, 
    [CollegeLevel] [char](1) NULL, 
    [NCRCategory] [char](1) NULL, 
    [CCLongTermId] [char](5) NULL, 
    [batch_id] [int] NULL 
)
```

These are the fields that need to be distinct to eliminate duplicates:

```
[StudentId] 
[CollegeId] 
[TermId] 
[CourseId]
```

The server that will be running this process has 8 cores, 32GB RAM, and SQL Server 2012.

Comment: The classic problem with deduplication is that what do you do in cases where you have conflicting data? Student, college, term and course all match but one source specifies the CreditFlag is Y, the other is N. Which wins? Does it always win? Across all fields? What if a value is provided in the non-authoritative source but doesn't exist in the authoritative? When I worked in marketing, we'd hold onto any method of contacting you, even if it's not the "good" source, we *might* be able to use it get a hold of you.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. Defining what is kept and what goes is very important. However, this data set is used for metrics and KPIs. Having duplicates can be detrimental. So, if the record has the four columns met, it stays. Otherwise it needs to be put into a queue to be reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite clustered index on all 4 columns on both tables. Create the destination table with a standard identity field primary key clustered index, but with a composite nonclustered index on those 4 columns. Insert into destination table from table01, using a derived table that also exposes ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentId, CollegeId, TermId, CourseId), and filter out all rows except for those with ROW_NUMBER of 1. That will dedupe table01. Then do the same thing with table02, but also using a NOT EXISTS to check against the destination table to make sure that a row does not already exist.